# Couldn't resolve host using curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

If I use

```
curl localhost:1234/urlpart/urlpart2
```

in an ssh terimal, I get the expected values returned. If I use it in PHP though, I get

> Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'curl localhost'

Here is the PHP used

```
<?php 

        $ch=curl_init('curl localhost:1234/urlpart/urlpart2');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result=@curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch); 
        echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: *sigh* what about leaving the "curl" away in there? I mean the error _tells_ you so. And the documentation of the function clearly says that a _url_ is expected as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Change the first line to

```
$ch=curl_init('http://localhost:1234/urlpart/urlpart2');
```